# Capture video from usb camera with javafx

Tags: camera, usb, javafx

Is any way to capture video from usb camera with javafx or other way with java except jmf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, javafx.scene.media provides playback support only.

From the documentation -

```
public Media(java.lang.String source)
```

> Constructs a Media instance. This is the only way to specify the media
>   source. The source must represent a valid URI and is immutable. Only
>   HTTP, FILE, and JAR URLs are supported. If the provided URL is invalid
>   then an exception will be thrown.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/simpleplayer.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html